# How to customize datepicker dialog position while using jQuery UI?

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I need to have dialog box under the `input` field. The default behavior - to display above the filed. Tried to customize it using `dialog` method - haven't worked. What is the  proper way to do it?

```
 <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#adv-issue-date" ).datepicker();

            var handler = function() {};
            var dp-settings-param = "";
            var dp-pos = [100, 200];

            $( "#adv-issue-date" ).datepicker( "dialog", "10/12/2012, handler, dp-settings-param, dp-pos" );
            });
        </script>
```

UPDATE:

The `datepicker` dialog is not showing because of empty `handler`. This way also does not works :

```
var handler = function() {$( "#adv-issue-date" ).datepicker("show");};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `.ui-datepicker` in the CSS file.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get current pos of input and display datepicker dialog just under it (so input field would be visible) ?

Comment: By default, the datepicker dialog does appear below the input field. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually move the datePicker around:

```
    $(document).ready(DocReady);

    function DocReady()
    {
        $("#adv-issue-date").datepicker({ beforeShow: moveDatePicker });    
    }

    function moveDatePicker(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv.css({ marginLeft: "200px", marginTop: "200px" });
    }
```